# Bootstrap Nav Width Appears Different in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have searched through a ton of articles here trying the fixes for this issue with no luck. Wanted to see if there is a fix for this I am overseeing on our company site.

Issue: I develop in FireFox and once was done with the beta version of the site I found a bug when viewing in Chrome. The issue is that the nav bar is shorter in Chrome & IE and looks perfect in FF and Safari. Below is the HTML and CSS for this section. You can see in the screen the differences in the way it's displaying if you click the image link. Thank You in advance for any insight!

[Navigation Bar Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARSmA.png)

```
CSS
.navigation {
min-height: 50px;
}

.navigation .navbar {
border: none;
margin-bottom: 0;
min-height: 50px;
}
.navigation .navbar .navbar-brand {
color: #fff;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 700;
height: 70px;
line-height: 35px;
}
.navigation .navbar-default {
background-color: #0091D5;
box-shadow: 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
clear: both;
}
.navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
color: #fff;
font-weight: 700;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
background: #FF7200;
color: #FFFFFF;
 }
.navigation .btn-default:hover,
.navigation .btn-default:focus,
.navigation .btn-default:active,
.navigation .btn-default.active {
 border-color: transparent;

}

HTML
    <section id="menu">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        </div> <!-- end .navbar-header -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul id="ulnav" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
         <li><a href="index.html" target="_parent">&nbsp;Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="water-damage.html" target="_parent">Water Damage</a></li>
             <li><a href="fire-damage.html" target="_parent">Fire</a></li>
            <li><a href="drying-services.html" target="_parent">Drying Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="restoration.html" target="_parent">Restoration</a></li>
            <li><a href="commercial.html" target="_parent">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="reviews.html" target="_parent">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="insurance-financing.html" target="_parent">Insurance & Financing</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" target="_parent">About</a></li>
            <li class="cwaf-bg"><a href="free-estimate.html" target="_parent">Free Estimate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try your snippet into codepen, and it's no problem in Chrome or Opera. both of them use webkit as engine

make sure your other style (global style) not give an effect to your navigation

Comment: Thanks! We ended up reprogramming the nav. Thank you for the reply!